# parameter syntax in ibatis

Tags: xml, orm, jdbc, dao, ibatis

What is the difference between the following in ibatis:

When I use the second format I get the follwing exception
java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

1)

```
 UPDATE TRAN_ITEM 
            SET BOOK_HNDL_MARK_T=#marksAndNumbers#,
                MDSE_CRGO_DESC_T=#cargoDesc#, 
                UPDT_PGM_I = 'OTM-RTS' 
                WHERE 
            TRAN_ITEM_I=#instanceId#
```

2)

```
UPDATE TRAN_ITEM SET 
BOOK_HNDL_MARK_T='$marksAndNumbers$',
MDSE_CRGO_DESC_T='$cargoDesc$', 
UPDT_PGM_I = 'OTM-RTS' 
WHERE TRAN_ITEM_I='$instanceId$'
```

my DAO as follows:

```
paramMap.put("marksAndNumbers", poItemDetailVO
                        .getMarksAndNumbers());
paramMap.put("cargoDesc", poItemDetailVO.getCargoDescription());
paramMap.put("instanceId", Integer.valueOf(Long                         .toString(poItemDetailVO.getInstanceID())));
```

Answer (score 0):

In second query you are putting (') before/after the input variables.

Comment: u mean # and $ dont have any difference?

Comment: If you are getting In OUT exception.. It means you are not sending the parameters with query.. Check your impl.. Share the code, where you executing the query.